# How to gank as a Mid laner

Tags: league-of-legends

I see every almost every enemy Mid laner knowing when to gank bot or top, or at least ganking even if the timing is not right, but me. I don't really know when to gank bot or top or where to place wards to catch off guard the enemy Jungler and get an easy kill.

Even if I kill my enemy laner I will keep farming the wave that is in front of me and probably the next one as well under the enemy turret. The chances of me going to gank bot sadly are extremely low.

I would like to get some tips on **when** to gank bot or top since it seems that I can't really find any time in the game to gank other lane because I'll be too busy farming.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22685/what-is-the-right-time-to-gank this may be helpful

Comment: Remember, a gank does not have to get a kill to be impactful. You can apply map pressure simply by leaving lane.  However, if you leave at the wrong time you will be causing more hurt to yourself than it is worth.  Just keep practicing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing when to gank comes largely from experience and practice, but Ive found the following to be very useful in knowing when is a good time to gank.

- Are the side lanes pushed up/overextended?
  If your team is pushing, you will have a really hard time ganking unless you want to dive them, which is a lot riskier.
- Is the enemy laner there?
  If you just killed, or forced your lane opponent to back, if you push the wave in, then you have a good opportunity to gank. I don't advise ganking if the lane is pushed towards your tower though.
- Are there wards?
  Do you know if the other team has placed wards recently? Try to keep track of where all the wards are so you can avoid them when going to gank. Walking over a ward makes you walking all the way to the other lane a waste of time
- Where are your wards?
  One spot I love to put a ward is in the brush between the enemy red and river. You can often catch a jungler off-guard or low and effectively 'gank' him in his own jungle as he goes around clearing his camps. As well, you can use wards to avoid getting counter-ganked, which also sucks.
- Practice!
  If you're not sure about when to gank, the best way to learn is to go and do it more!
  People learn really well from experience, so if you fail miserably your first few ganks, dont be discouraged. Get back to lane, farm up, and try again the next time you 1v1 the other mid laner.
- Do you have flash? (Thanks to [dphil's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177294/how-to-gank-as-a-mid-laner#comment241192_177301))
  Having flash allows you to take a riskier/stealthier/shorter gank path to avoid wards and such. If you get caught out you can quickly escape over a wall if you're not playing someone with some sort of dash. It also lets you secure kills more easilly during the gank.

Comment: Do note that, before you gank, shove your lane up to turret so you don't lose xp/cs. Don't spend too much time trying to set up the gank either because time is money.

Comment: Add in another.  Do you have flash?  That allows you to take riskier/stealthier gank paths to avoid wards so you can flash over walls to escape if they collapse.

Comment: it also has alot to do with what hero are you playing / what hero the enemy lane is playing / what hero your teammates are playing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you the enemy mid laner is missing in action on mid, you should push the wave to his turret. Then you can either recall, hit the turret, kill dragon or gank a lane. You should always try to gank the lanes that are most pushed. A nice thing to do is to keep an eye on the junglers. Yes, both! If your jungler is top, the enemy bot lane will often feel safe from ganks and might not ward their lanes immediately which makes them vulnerable to ganks. It also depends on which champion you play. Fizz is an excellent ganker. The term we are looking for is roaming. It means that you leave your lane to pressure other lanes. Fizz is great because he has enormous burst damage and can quickly escape. An example of a bad ganker would be Anivia because she is way too slow. However, it's still possible with the help of your teammate at that lane.